# node.js rest client chrash after server shutdown

Tags: node.js, rest, tcp, restify

I have a question about node.js rest client restify.
So I make request on server and I get a response (it prints nice on console) but when I shutdown my server my rest client chrashes with error :

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error event
              ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11
    at TCP.onread (net.js:556:19
```

My code is simple :

```
var restify = require('restify');

// Creates a JSON client
var client = restify.createJsonClient({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/check'
});

client.get('', function(err, req, res, obj) {    
  console.log(obj);  // print response
});
```

My server is also written in node.js and uses express framework and standard API which works for months on production so I doubt it is problem in that.
Looks like client didn't close TCP connection to server but in restify tutorials I didn't find instructions to do that.

Thanks for any informations!

Comment: I think it won't show the predifined error if you handle it in `server.on('disconnect',function(){.....});` Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @sumitb.mdi He is asking about client side.

Comment: I can't repeat... which node version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Add `agent: false` to your json client creation:

```
var client = restify.createJsonClient({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/check',
    agent: false
});
```

This way the TCP connection will be closed every time and you won't get error if the server is closed after you receive your response.